# Unity Resolving Android Dependencies extremely slow

Tags: android, maven, unity-game-engine, admob

When I import the Admob SDK into my unity project, the auto resolving is start but it often takes long time(about 2 hours)to finish to progress
Here is my project setting:

Platform：Android

Unity version: 2021.3.16f1

[image: details]
[image: details]

I think may be the problem is about the network, I living in China so I guess when Android Resolver try to connect to the maven.com will be slow down but I have no idea how to improve the speed.

Comment: Use the proxy for China for Android Studio and get the dependencies there.

Answer (score 0):

Because of limitations in China, the only possible solution for you is to use a proxy/VPN to connect.